# Is it possible to execute code using a URL?

Tags: php, security

Is it possible for someone to execute a code through a URL for example

```
http://localhost/page.php?code=echo 'something';
```

If yes then how can it be done and how can you prevent it from happening?

Comment: you mean executing PHP code ? you can't, unless your PHP script parses & handles the query string very well.

Comment: Execute code where? On the server? On the client?

Comment: You may go for javascript. check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279557/how-to-execute-javascript-code-using-variable-in-url

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Sure you can.

Comment: You cannot execute PHP like that, normally, but maybe you could read about XSS.

Comment: You can, if the server side code is severely broken. But you'd have to really try to make that kind of mistake.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO by how ? some JavaScript is okay, but PHP is not okay.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: @Juhana — It is hard to make the sort of mistake where PHP gets executed by accident, but very easy to allow JavaScript or SQL to be executed (W3Schools have plenty of tutorials that teach you how).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible if something on the server takes the data in the URL and puts it somewhere where it might be treated as code (e.g. in an `eval` statement, in an SQL query or in an HTML document).

The defences are all specific to the place where you put the data, but usually involve escaping it.

See also [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), and [the open web application security project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page).

Answer (score 0):

After looking around for a while, I found eval which is a function that is capable of executing any php code provided in a GET like my example above, I used the following code to test it.

```
<?php
$code = $_REQUEST['code'];
eval($code);
?>
```